# AJAX - PHP & XML - POST request is directing to the PHP file instead of staying at the original page

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax

I have been trying recently to use AJAX in a form I posses in order to prevent the page from reloading. I learned AJAX through thenewboston's videos and I've tried to match it to my form.

### HTML:

```
<label for="f_name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="f_name" id="f_name" />
<label for="f_email">E-Mail:</label>
<input type="text" name="f_email" id="f_email" />
<label for="f_subj">Subject:</label>
<input type="text" name="f_subj" id="f_subj" /><br />
<div id="status"></div>
<button id="b_send" onClick="process()">Send</button>
```

### JavaScript

```
function process() {
    var name = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("f_name").value);
    var email = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("f_email").value);
    var sbj = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("f_subj").value);
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        xmlHttp.open("POST", "send.php", true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send("name="+name+"&email="+email+"&subj="+sbj);
    } else {
        setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    }
}
function handleServerResponse() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) { // AJAX is ready!
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) { // 200 = Comms went OK!
            var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            var xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            var message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = '<span style="color:blue">' + message + '</span>';
        } else {
            alert('Something went wrong!');
        }
    }
```

### PHP:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sbj = $_POST['subj'];
$src = 'BETA';
$to = "someone@somewhere.com";
$subject = "CONTACT | From: " . $name . " , " . $email . " | '" . $sbj . "' | " . $src . "";
$body = "
        <html><body>
        <h4>From: ".$name." , ".$email."</h4>
        <h4>Subject: ".$sbj."</h4>
        <h5>Source: BETA</h5>
        </body></html>";
$headers = "From: someone@somewhere.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: \r\n";
$headers .= "CC: \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$response = 'Error!';

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    $response = 'Sent!';
} else {
    $response = 'Error 202!';
}

echo '<response>';
echo strip_tags($response);
echo '</response>';
exit(); // I had to use exit() due to my hosting adding up code after every PHP page.
?>
```

After I click on the button, it shows me the PHP page with the following saying:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.

and the XML code below it:

```
<response>Sent!</response>
```

So what now?

Comment: I tried using your code and it seems to work perfectly fine. I get the AJAX response back in the original page itself.

Answer (score 0):

The message is a warning. An XML document is a data structure but does not contain any presentation/style information internally. Normally an XML document is used in inter-application communication or as a pure data structure that is then used with additional presentation/style information to display to users.

You are outputing your data in `xml` format using following lines,

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';
```

If you are trying to get the response from your ajax call, remove xml header and simply `echo` proper response or use `JSON` to get your data.

or if you want to display xml file without the warning, you can attach a stylesheet to your xml document like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="your_stylesheet.css"?>
```

XML-Stylesheet Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/

Comment: But using the original code as-is itself works for me (that is, including the first two lines).